# Import appcompat to new eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, import, android-appcompat

I just installed new eclipse version Neon Release 4.6.0, and downloaded sdk manager from there I downloaded all things but still can't find appcompat on: android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support folder..

[image]

I read alot of posts they are saying that you have to go on support folder but I have no support folder I just have :

```
> D:\Eclipse\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\gapid
> D:\Eclipse\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\gapid_3
> D:\Eclipse\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\m2repository
```

And my problem is when I create and Android Application I see errors on:

```
extends ActionBarActivity
```

and there is red lined this line too:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

and alot of other lines in project for examplre R.fdf.dfd

Any idea how to import that library to may workspace and work ?
I found some files but cant make my project work I found them here :

```
\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7
```

Comment: Question: Are you using Gradle? Why install the latest Eclipse and not Android Studio?

Comment: I have used android studio for a while, and now I'm back on it, So I'm not a professional so I just play around with it so I love the Eclipse, I just Create a new project and make any application for fun.. so any help ?

Comment: and I have no clue what is Gradle, never used it

Comment: [Gradle is a build-tool that is used to build Android projects](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html). Overall, I find JetBrains IDEs much better over Eclipse. There is a learning curve just like when you first started using Eclipse, I'm sure, though, so again, why bother using Eclipse when Android support for it has ended.

Comment: Is easy to import my eclipse projects to Android studio ?

Comment: Yup, [documentation for that](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html)